# Longest cooldown time ever in DOTA 2

Tags: dota-2

I visited many sites about DOTA 2 , but none of them gave information about cooldown time for each hero in DOTA 2 . As far as I know the longest cooldown time is Silencer's Global Silence with 160 seconds , but I'm not so sure about that , maybe Wraith Kings' Reincarnation , or Enigma's Black Hole have longer cooldown time ? I don't know. Could you give a list about cooldown time ?

Comment: Listing it for every character would take a *very long* time, and probably makes this question too broad for this site.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are some of the longest cooldowns in the game.  Unless I have missed one, this *should* be every skill with a cooldown greater than 120 seconds.  Note that some of these cooldowns are accurate only for having 1 level in the skill.

- Keeper of the Light's "Will-O-Wisp": 120s
- Bane's "Fiend's Grip": 120s
- Lone Druid's "Summon Spirit Bear": 120s
- Sand King's "Epicenter": 120s
- Necrophos's "Reaper's Scythe": 120s
- Visage's "Summon Familiars": 130s
- Monkey King's "Wukong's Command": 130s
- Magnus's "Reverse Polarity": 130s
- Silencer's "Global Silence": 130s
- Lycan's "Shapeshift": 130s
- Queen of Pain's "Sonic Wave": 135s
- Venomancer's "Poison Nova": 140s
- Mirana's "Moonlight Shadow": 140s
- Juggernaut's "Omnislash": 140s
- Night Stalker's "Dark Ascension": 140s
- Brewmaster's "Primal Split": 140s
- Luna's "Eclipse": 140s
- Death Prophet's "Exorcism": 145s
- Chaos Knight's "Phantasm": 145s
- Doom's "Doom": 145s
- Earthshaker's "Echo Slam": 150s
- Tidehunter's "Ravage": 150s
- Terrorblade's "Metamorphosis": 155s
- Omniknight's "Guardian Angel": 160s
- Outworld Devourer's "Sanity's Eclipse": 160s
- Naga Siren's "Song of the Siren": 160s
- Warlock's "Chaotic Offering": 170s
- Spectre's "Haunt": 180s
- Wraith King's "Reincarnation": 200s
- Enigma's "Black Hole": 200s
- Techies's "Minefield Sign": 360s

As you can see, the longest cooldown is the "Minefield Sign" ability from Techies.

All information sourced from the Dota 2 Wiki.  Also, it is possible that I have missed an ability.  115+ heroes is a lot to look through :)